# Snap.SVG EDGE / IE - jQuery Animation stops

Tags: jquery, svg, jquery-animate, snap.svg, svg-animate

Hi I am having an issue with an animation just stopping in the middle of it running in IE and EDGE (fine in Chrome).

I get the alert "after text" but the opacity of the "textone1" etc is still sat at 0 in the dev tools and IE just stops the animation altogether.

I do get a console error in IE "Object doesn't support property or method 'getCTM'  -  snap.svg-min.js (19,26680)" which I don't get in Chrome.

Here is the code it stops at when running:

HTML:

```
<g xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="text" style="opacity: 1;" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -70 -150)">
<text id="XMLID_2_">
  <tspan class="st1 st2 bold textone1" style="opacity: 0;" x="-20" y="0">TEXT1</tspan>
  <tspan class="st3 st2 textone2" style="opacity: 0;" x="74" y="0">TEXT2</tspan>
  <tspan class="st3 st2 textone3" style="opacity: 0;" x="15" y="50">TEXT3</tspan>
  <tspan class="st4 st2 bold textone4" style="opacity: 0;" x="305" y="50">TEXT4</tspan>
  <tspan class="st3 st2 textone4" style="opacity: 0;" x="640" y="50">.</tspan>
</text>
</g>
```

JS:

```
var text = s.selectAll("#text");
var textone1 = s.selectAll("#text .textone1");
var textone2 = s.selectAll("#text .textone2");
var textone3 = s.selectAll("#text .textone3");
var textone4 = s.selectAll("#text .textone4");

textone1.attr({
    opacity: 0
});
textone2.attr({
    opacity: 0
});
textone3.attr({
    opacity: 0
});
textone4.attr({
    opacity: 0
});

text.animate({
    transform: "t-290,-150",
    opacity:0,
}, 0, mina.easein, function() {
});

text.animate({
          transform: "t-70,-150",
          opacity: 1
        }, 0, mina.easeinout,function() {

          alert("after text");

        textone1.animate({
          transform: "t-290,-150",
          opacity: 1
        }, 500, mina.easeinout);

          textone2.animate({
            transform: "t-290,-150",
            opacity: 1
          }, 1000, mina.easeinout);

            textone3.animate({
              transform: "t-290,-150",
              opacity: 1
            }, 1000, mina.easeinout);

              textone4.animate({
                transform: "t-290,-150",
                opacity: 1
              }, 1000, mina.easeinout);

});
```

Can anyone see what I might be doing wrong to cause IE/EDGE to stop?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure you can apply a transform correctly to a tspan element.

Comment: @Ian Hi Ian, ah right ok so how would I get around this I am trying to fade the tpsan in, it works in Chrome is that just an IE thing?

Comment: @Ian Tried to use fill-opacity instead with no luck!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like @Ian pointed me in the right direction.

For some reason IE does not like opacity on a tspan element, I instead applied these to the g tags and it works fine.

Another reason to love IE :)